# What is wrong with my code? python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am Programming in python however i have come to a slight glitch which i cannot solve! The issue is that when it prints out in a text files it only prints one line of the whole output! Otherwise it works! Please i need help to make this work!

```
import sys, bz2, string, os
#instead of hardcoding filename, get it from arguments
#filename = os.getcwd()
filename = raw_input("Enter the path of bz2 document e.g. files/access_log-20130301.bz2: ")
print "Using file : " + filename
source_file = bz2.BZ2File(filename, "r") 
for line in source_file:
    #Extract the date and put into a variable 
    logdate = string.split(line)[3][1:12]
    #Extract movie name and put into variable movie
    movie = string.split(line)[6]
    #extract who read the movie username = 
    usernames = string.split(line)[2]
    #Only process the movie line if we have /media/movie in it. 
    if movie.find('media/movies') > 0:
        #Prints all things prosscesed
        print "User:" + usernames + " On:" +  logdate + " Was watching:"+ movie
        #p=open(filename+"record.txt", "w")
        fp=open(filename+"record.txt", "wb+")
        fp.write("User: " + usernames + " On: " +  logdate + " Was watching: "+ movie+" File from:"+filename+"\n")
sys.exit()
```

Comment: As a note, when working with files, it's a good idea to use [the `with` statement](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lRaKmobSXF4) to open and close them.

Comment: This looks more like `Python 2` to me.  Why both tags?

Comment: Can you upload your output? Possibly, a Dropbox or SkyDrive or Pastebin link?

Comment: The problem is that `open(filename+"record.txt", "w")` truncates the file every time so you only get the last line. Use "a" mode to append or better yet, pull the open out of the loop as given in @Kirk Strauser 's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is likely that you are opening a new file handle for the file each time you want to write a line, and you do not flush the output first.  There are two possible solutions here:

1. Open the file you intend to write to before your main `for` loop.  This way you will only have one file handle, and a lack of flushing will not cause this behavior.  Make sure you close the file when you are done.  (Consider using a `with` block, which will cause the file to be closed automatically at the termination of the block: `with open(filename + "record.txt", "wb+") as f:`)
2. Close `fp` immediately after the `fp.write()` call, which will force any buffered output to be flushed, at least to the kernel I/O cache.

I would prefer option 1, as there is no reason to open and close the file multiple times in this case.  (If you are writing many lines to the file, these open/flush/close cycles will wind up wasting a lot of time!)

Option 1 would look something like this:

```
import sys, bz2, string, os
#instead of hardcoding filename, get it from arguments
#filename = os.getcwd()
filename = raw_input("Enter the path of bz2 document e.g. files/access_log-20130301.bz2: ")
print "Using file : " + filename
with open(filename+"record.txt", "wb+") as fp:
    source_file = bz2.BZ2File(filename, "r") 
    for line in source_file:
        #Extract the date and put into a variable 
        logdate = string.split(line)[3][1:12]
        #Extract movie name and put into variable movie
        movie = string.split(line)[6]
        #extract who read the movie username = 
        usernames = string.split(line)[2]
        #Only process the movie line if we have /media/movie in it. 
        if movie.find('media/movies') > 0:
            #Prints all things prosscesed
            print "User:" + usernames + " On:" +  logdate + " Was watching:"+ movie
            #p=open(filename+"record.txt", "w")
            fp.write("User: " + usernames + " On: " +  logdate + " Was watching: "+ movie+" File from:"+filename+"\n")

# The with block has ended at this point, so the file will already be closed here.

sys.exit()
```

Answer (score 1):

You're opening the output file in write mode inside the loop. Open it once outside your main loop.

Be sure to close it when you're done. Even better, write that like:

```
with open(filename + "record.txt", "wb+") as fp:
    for line in source_file:
        ...
        fp.write(...)
```

so that the `open` context manager closes it for you afterward.

Comment: Shouldn't mode be "w" instead of "wb+"? The "b" says binary which will cause funky line endings on windows. Teh "+" says readable, but its only being written to.

Comment: Yeah, probably. I was trying to show the minimum number of changes so that he could see how the "before" lines mapped to the "after" lines.